# java scanner: how prevent enter spam

Tags: java, validation, java.util.scanner, newline, numeric

I have a user input validate function:

```
public int UserChoiceValidate() {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int choice;
    do {
        System.out.print("Please enter your choice: ");
        while (!sc.hasNextInt()) {
            System.out.print("Input invalid, please retry: ");
            sc.nextLine(); // consume left over
        }
        choice = sc.nextInt();
        if (choice <= 0 || choice > 5) {
            System.out.println("Choice not included, please retry");
        }
    } while (choice <= 0 || choice > 5);
    return choice;
}
```

The code will repeat

> Input invalid, please retry:Input invalid, please retry:Input invalid, please retry:

when I spam enter and then type in an invalid input.

How do I fix this error without having to rewrite it as reading a String instead of an int. I have quite a few functions with the same struction and would like to avoid having to rewrite them all.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain what you mean by "rewrite it as a string validation", you are currently ignoring whatever input the user provides that isn't an `int`; if you want to treat "enter spam" special, you could do something like

```
System.out.print("Please enter your choice: ");
while (!sc.hasNextInt()) {
    String line = sc.nextLine();
    if (line.isEmpty()) {
        continue;
    }
    System.out.print("Input invalid, please retry: ");
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Works great. I was trying to avoid having to accept input as a string, check regex, then use parseInt().